# How do you programatically select values in TreeView that uses data binding in WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, treeview

I want my program to automatically select the most recently created object when it's added to the list. Here's the current code which doesn't work:

```
    public static void CreateResourceTree(TreeView selector,IEnumerable<Resource> resources,Resource onRefresh=null)
    {
        ActiveResources.Clear();
        ActiveResources.AddRange(resources.OrderByDescending(x=>x.FetchMeta("Priority").IntValue)
        .ThenBy(x=>x.Label)
        .ToList());
        selector.Items.Refresh();
        selector.SelectedItem=onRefresh;
    }
```

The code is meant to set the value to the value of `onRefresh` Unfortunately, SelectedItem as ReadOnly, which results in an error.

When I Googled the issue, the only solution I found to programatically selecting an item is to use the "IsSelected" property on a TreeViewItem, but since this is data-bound, it doesn't use or recognize TreeViewItem objects.

Here is the XAML code, in case it's needed:

```
    <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding ResourceList}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" x:Name="ResourcesTree" SelectedItemChanged="ResourcesTree_OnSelectedItemChanged" Margin="0,4,0,0">
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type xmlclass:Resource}" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
                <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Output}" />
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    </TreeView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your Resource in some sort of ViewModel or just create a sub class with an IsSelected property.

e.g.

```
public class SelectableResource : Resource
{
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}
```

Then create a style to bind the TreeViewItem.IsSelected to your new property:

```
<TreeView.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
        <Setter Property="IsSelected"
                Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    </Style>
</TreeView.Resources>
```

You can now set the selected items from the data side, rather than trying to control the view manually.

```
public static void CreateResourceTree(TreeView selector,IEnumerable<SelectableResource> resources,SelectableResource onRefresh=null)
{
    ActiveResources.Clear();
    ActiveResources.AddRange(resources.OrderByDescending(x=>x.FetchMeta("Priority").IntValue)
    .ThenBy(x=>x.Label)
    .ToList());

    onRefresh.IsSelected = true;
}
```